# Callback function after an assignment

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an angular app and Angular is very opinionated about separations of concerns.

I have a controller and a service and I don't want my code to break separations of concerns.

In my controller I am trying to get data from a web service and then all another web service with the data received from the first - and due to javascript asynchronous nature I can't figure out a good way to do this without crossing the line in terms of separation of concerns.

Here is a jsfiddle that shows it:

http://jsfiddle.net/yak2m1ve/

Now keep in mind I am trying to find an elegant solution that doesn't break SoC - not a dirty hack to make it work.

```
//controller
var x = fn1();
var y = fn2(x);

alert(y);

//service
function fn1(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        return '123'; //web request example
    }, 1000);
}

function fn2(code){
    return 'asdfb' + code;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plunker although represents the problem in terms of plain function calls, it is evident that you'll be making web service calls instead.

You, in this case, need to use [Angular Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

For example, assume that you are ought to perform the following sequence of operations.

> 1. Retrieve a movie details.
> 2. Retrieve it's star cast.
> 3. Assign the response to the Scope variable.

In your service, you'll have

```
    this.getMovie = function(movie) {
        return $http.get('/api/v1/movies/' + movie)
               .then(
                  function (response) {
                    return {
                       title: response.data.title,
                       cost:  response.data.price
                    });
                  });
    };

    this.starCast = function(movie) {
        return $http.get('/api/v1/movies/' + movie)
               .then(
                  function (response) {
                    return {
                       title: response.data.title,
                       cost:  response.data.price
                    });
                  });
    };
```

And in your controller :

```
    $scope.getMovie = function(movie) {
       service.getMovie(movie) 
       .then(function(movieData) {
          service.getStarCast(movieData).then(function(response) {
              $scope.starCast = response;
            });  
       });
    };
```